# Ms Access - Can't remove line breaks from Word RTF report export

Tags: ms-access

I have built a project management database using Access 2016 and I added the possibility to export reports in .rtf. The report is composed of several text boxes including the title, description and dates of the project.

Everything works fine but when the report opens in Word there are line breaks at every line which makes it super hard to copy/paste the description text to use it elsewhere.

I looked into a lot of different forums but never find a way to remove those line breaks. For now I only tried to change the format of the text boxes from Plain text to rich text but it didn't work.

All ideas are more than welcome as I'm running in circles for two weeks now...

[This is a screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIGld.png)

Comment: Please provide more information. How are you exporting to the RTF file (using the export data wizard, or VBA?) Where do the breaks appear (between fields, between records or both?)

Comment: Hi Erik! I export the RTF file by using the "ExportWithFormatting" macro from the Action catalog. They appear between two lines of text so not really between fields and records, but between lines of a text (from a record) that is more than one line long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a small clean-up function that will search and remove the line breaks (RTF code: `\par`) in the generated RTF file.

1. Skip the first line breaks (*Title, Subject*)
2. Skip the `\pard` codes, if any (lead of your description)
3. Search and remove all subsequent `\par`

Comment: Thanks for that, I think this might actually work. I'll test it out and keep you udpated.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't remove the *line breaks*, neither the *tabs*, nor the *spaces*, only the signs for these.

But that is a setting of your RTF viewer. Your export has no control over that.

Comment: Hi Gutav! So you mean that it would be impossible to remove those breaks between lines from Access, right?

Comment: No, but you would do that by redesigning the report. The export tries to mimic the report, so if you wish a single wide line with no linebreaks, adjust the width of the textbox on the report and - probably - also the width (paper size) of the report.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gustav! Sadly, I tried to adjust the width of both report and text boxes but I still have line breaks when my text is more than two lines.

Comment: You could try using a smaller font size. I don't know of other options.

Comment: I have several lines per paragraph, so a small font would not work. But I'll keep it mind for future reports.